# Quel auxiliaire pour les verbes « paraitre » et « apparaitre » ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, auxiliaires

Les verbes *paraitre* et *apparaitre* se conjuguent-ils avec l'auxiliaire *être* ou *avoir* ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ces verbes peuvent être conjugués avec les deux auxiliaires.

Pour le verbe *paraître*, l'auxiliaire peut changer le sens de la phrase. Lorsque l'auxiliaire *être* est employé, le verbe signifie *se montrer, se présenter* ou *être publié*. Lorsqu'il est utilisé avec l'auxiliaire *avoir*, il a le sens de *sembler*, *donner l'impression*.

> La nouvelle est parue dans le journal.
> Jean n'est pas paru au bureau depuis trois jours.
>
> Le vol m'a paru très long.
> Les enfants m'ont paru nerveux.

Pour le verbe *apparaître*, il s'emploie principalement avec l'auxiliaire *être*, mais peut être utilisé avec l'auxiliaire *avoir* pour insister sur l'action plutôt que l'état. L'utilisation de l'auxiliaire *être* a cependant tendance à remplacer *avoir* dans tous les cas, mais les deux sont corrects.

> Il est apparu à Noël chargé de cadeaux.
>
> Des traces ont apparu à la surface.

Voir la [définition de *paraître*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/para%C3%AEtre/57914?q=paraitre#57576) et les [difficultés de *apparaître*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/appara%C3%AEtre/4622/difficulte) dans le *Larousse*.

Answer (score 5):

Les deux auxiliaires s'emploient, avec des nuances de sens.

Ces nuances sont parfois assez subtiles. Je cite l'OQLF:

> Lorsqu’il est question d’une publication, *paraître* peut recevoir les deux auxiliaires, mais avec une nuance de sens propre à chacun d’eux. La conjugaison avec *avoir* insiste sur la publication même, l’action de publier, tandis que la conjugaison avec *être* met l’accent sur la publication vue dans son résultat, comme un fait accompli.

Voir les exemples et les précisions dans les articles en question: [*paraitre*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3843) et [*apparaître*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3848).

Answer (score 0):

Trouvé sur d'autres sites Web.

- http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3852 :

  > Si apparaître et paraître peuvent tous deux signifier « devenir visible », apparaître suggère un caractère soudain (« devenir soudainement visible, évident »), alors que paraître renvoie davantage à une action attendue, moins brusque. À cette nuance sémantique s’ajoute une autre différence : paraître se conjugue généralement avec avoir et apparaître, à l’inverse, généralement avec être.
  >
  > Exemples :
  >
  > - On ne sait pas où il est, il n’a pas paru au bureau depuis deux jours.
  > - Le soleil n’a paru que quelques minutes à la fin de l’après-midi.
  > - Des difficultés imprévues sont apparues.
  > - La vérité lui est soudainement apparue.
  > - Des taches sont apparues sur sa peau.
- http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=175588&p=1106971#post1106971

  > Avec **être** on insiste sur l'état alors qu'avec **avoir** on insiste plus sur l'action. 
  >   Mais on en réalité on utilise quasiment jamais avoir... 
  >   Apparaître peut se conjuguer avec avoir parce qu'il peut par moment être employé de façon transitive.